# SwiftUI how come this is happening?

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm : ViewModel
    @State private var username = ""
    private var searchAllowed : Bool{
        if(username.count>2)
        {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Text("Enter your Username:")
                    .font(.title.bold())
                
                
                TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    .frame(width: 280)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                
                
                NavigationLink{
                    if (vm.apiLoaded)
                    {
                        ProfileView(vm: vm)
                    }
                    else{
                        ProgressView()
                            .task {
                                await vm.userToUUID(username: username)
                                await vm.fetchPlayerData()
                            }
                    }
                } label:
                {
                    ZStack{
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .fill(.gray)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                            
                        Text("Search")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            
                            
                }
            }
                .disabled(searchAllowed)
        }
        
        }
    }
    
}
```

So I have these two `Views` with two `async` methods getting called in the else clause in the `NavigationLink`, but my problem is that I'm not getting the expected result and I'm assuming that's because both `async` functions start running at the same time.

The `fetchPlayerData` one uses `UUID` to get the `PlayerData`, is there some way I can make it get the `UUID` first and only then `fetchPlayerData`?
ViewModel:

```
import Foundation

@MainActor final class ViewModel : ObservableObject{

    @Published var apiLoaded : Bool = false

    @Published var player : Player? //player is kinda our model

    func userToUUID(username : String) async  {
        let playersURLString = "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft//(username)"
        if let url = URL(string: playersURLString){
            do{
                let (data, ) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let uuid = try decoder.decode(UUIDConversion.self, from: data).id
                print(uuid)
                player?.uuid = uuid

            } catch{
                print("bad")
            }
        }
    }
    func fetchPlayerData() async{
        let playersURLString = "https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=key&uuid=81f5de24b017466aaab4551a3fb38e5c"
        if let url = URL(string: playersURLString){
            do {
                let (data, ) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                player = try decoder.decode(ApiResponse.self, from: data).player
                print(player)
                apiLoaded = true
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: If I add a UUID property to my ViewModel and then set that in the UUID function if I refer to player.uuid then it works for some reason

```
@Published var uuid : String = ""
    @Published var player : Player? //player is kinda our model

    func userToUUID(username : String) async  {
        let playersURLString = "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft//(username)"
        if let url = URL(string: playersURLString){
            do{
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let uuid = try decoder.decode(UUIDConversion.self, from: data).id
                print(uuid)
                player?.uuid = uuid
                self.uuid = uuid

            } catch{
                print("bad")
            }
        }
    }
```

But there's something really weird here, in my profileview:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm : ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        List{

            VStack{
                Text(vm.player?.displayname ?? "T")
                    .padding(.vertical, 0)
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://crafatar.com/renders/body//(vm.uuid)%22)) { image in
                    image
                    .center()
                } placeholder: {
                    ProgressView()
                }

            }
```

vm.player?.displayname works and gives me the value but for some reason vm.player?.uuid doesn't work and only vm.uuid works..

Comment: Maybe show us those 2 functions?

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter I edited it to include both functions, basically I want the user's UUID to be stored somewhere(usertoUUID) and then call fetchPlayerData with that new specific UUID, I just realized my viewModel is optional and it only gets initialized by fetchPlayerData as well so player?.uuid = uuid probably returns nil, but so where can I store the UUID or how should I possibly do this?

Comment: "...but for some reason vm.player?.uuid doesn't work and only vm.uuid works...",
 `vm.uuid` is plain String, so `AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://crafatar.com/renders/body//(vm.uuid)%22)) { ...}` works (according to you).
 However `vm.player?.uuid` is an `Optional`, and so you must do what you did
 in `Text(vm.player?.displayname ?? "T")`, give it a default value, or
 make sure it is unwarped (using if let...).

Comment: Using optional for published bar is not good : the detected change will only when the var is set to some valid struct or set to nil. Changed inside it will not trigger redrawn.

Comment: @Ptit Xav, this is not my experience. I sometimes have an `ObservableObject` class model containing 
an optional var, for example: `@Published var item: Item?`, and any change to that var or to the content 
of `item` triggers a change in the View.